# How to use \polishhook symbol

Tags: symbols, font-encodings

I need to insert [polish hook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%98) into latex document.

Using comprehensive package I found, what `\polishhook{E}` is supported by wsuipa font package and `\polhk{E}` is supported by `mathscinet` package.

There are problems with both (for me at least). I want to use cm-super font package, not wsuipa, and I have to use T2A font encoding while `mathscinet` supports OT1 only.

Is there any solution of this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are looking for the standard LaTeX accent `\k`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\k{E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep! I asked a stupid question once again.

Comment: It works also with the T2A encoding (albeit building a composite character).

Answer (score 4):

With `\k{E}` under T2A encoding you get a composite character, which might be sufficient for your purposes. However, the composition is quite bad for `\k{e}` and not optimal for `\k{A}` and `\k{a}`, as can be seen from the picture

[image]

If you need both Russian and Polish text in your document, you should use `babel` features, so that the correct font encoding will be automatically chosen based on the current language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[polish,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}
Михаил Сергеевич Горбачёв

\foreignlanguage{polish}{Lech Wałęsa}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For now I needed this only for lowercase e symbol and `\k` is good. Unfortunately, I can't use `\foreignlanguage`, because this code is in .bib files, which are being parsed by biblatex. Using `\foreignlanguage` will low the readability.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, if you must use the OT1 encoding, you can use the `ogonek` package to fake the accent (with the `\k` command).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ogonek}

\begin{document}

chrz\k{a}szcz

\end{document}
```